# How to dynamically determine which Python subclass to create?

Tags: python

Say I have a `Word` class with subclasses `ShortWord` and `LongWord`. Is there a way to dynamically determine which subclass gets instantiated based on a given input? I mean I could define a separate function like

```py
def instantiate(text):
    if len(text) < 5:
        return ShortWord(text)
    else:
        return LongWord(text)
```

But that doesn't feel very (for lack of a better word) elegant. Is there a good way to go about this? I have found some similar questions in other languages, but nothing python-specific.

Comment: You can use an if-expression... but not much more. The code your are showing looks fine.

Comment: What you have is perfectly fine and normal. I would just make a better name than "instantiate".

Answer (score 1):

I would define a `@staticmethod` in the base class which makes the determination.

You might need to define a `__init_subclass__` in the base class to at least be aware of what classes are there, since you don't know about the subclasses before the base class is defined.

```
class Word(object):
    _tr = {}  # Type registry
    @staticmethod
    def instantiate(text):
        if len(text) < 5:
            cls = __class__._tr.get('ShortWord')
        else:
            cls = __class__._tr.get('LongWord')
        return cls(text) if cls is not None else None

    def __init_subclass__(cls):
        __class__._tr[cls.__name__] = cls


class ShortWord(Word):
    pass


class LongWord(Word):
    pass
```

---

I thought it over after seeing the comments, and this is another approach. Didn't want to submit two answers for one question. UPDATE: Thanks to @chepner's comment, I cleaned it up further.

```
class Word(object):
    @staticmethod
    def instantiate(text):
        if len(text) < 5:
            return ShortWord(text)
        else:
            return LongWord(text)


class ShortWord(Word):
    pass


class LongWord(Word):
    pass
```

Instantiate with `val = Word.instantiate(text)`

Comment: Knowing which subclasses exist won't help your determine which one to choose

Comment: I'm only looking at the OP's example. It was to dynamically call a constructor. I'm sure there are other ways, but by keeping as a static method of the base class, it keeps it in the class hierarchy.

Comment: I guess it's also possible to monkey patch the instantiate method AFTER all the subclasses are defined, and that would get rid of that `dict` and the `__init_subclass__` method, but I tend to avoid writing class families with monkey patching.

Comment: You don't need to define `instantiate` after the subclasses, then make the manual assignment to `Word.instantiate`. `ShortWord` and `LongWord` are just free variables that will be looked up when the method is *called*; they don't need to be defined before `instantiate` is defined.

Comment: @chepner Thanks for the clarification. Just easier (for me) to follow how what's being defined. I tend to look at source from top to bottom, and treat the definitions similarly.